# Alarms vs. TIME_TICK in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I'm not sure which is these is appropriate for my current application.

I need to switch wallpaper on a given, but user changeable, interval.  I've been using a BroadcastReceiver to check every minute, but then I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619133/hidden-features-of-android-development).

Is there any particular advantage to one method over another?  Right now I've got to keep a service alive to receive the broadcast, but would using alarms obviate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `AlarmManager` would mean you would not need to keep a service in memory all of the time. This is A Very Good Thing. ;-)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm pretty new to Java and didn't even know about the AlarmManager.  Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: @CommonsWare: As of end of 2023, what technologies are best suited to update a customized hour and minute (time)  i.e. customized notification of a calendar app  every minute? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bishwash: I do not know what a "customized notification of a calendar app every minute" is, sorry. However, doing something every minute is bad for the battery. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide more details of the app feature that you are looking to build.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks Android guru for your attention. I have gone mental infinite loop in this problem. You can only help. I have just posted a question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77736297/2789099 Thanks in advance.