# How to update notification power efficiently every minute to display time in hour and minute in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, alarmmanager

I have a calendar app which need to display Current Date and time and Events(Holidays) in the notification bar of a country(i.e India) even when app is closed or in Background. I made customized notification bar and implemented using remote views. I used broadcast receiver and foreground service to implement these functions. But i got too  many problems.

1. Notification disappears randomly in a day or two.
2. android.app.RemoteServiceException crash
3. android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException
4. Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

etc. Android introduces new features such as work manager instead of using foreground service however they do not allow updating every minute. But i need to show hour and minute and update it every minute. As of end of 2023 which technologies (Alarm Manager, Broadcast Receiver, BOOT_COMPLETED, ACTION_TICK, DATE_CHANGED, WorkManager, Handler, Timer etc) should i use to make an app ANR and crash free. I have attached image for better understanding. Please Help.  [image]

Comment: What you are seeking is impractical.

Comment: why it is so inefficient or battery consuming to update notification every minute?

Comment: Simply a TIME_TICK Broadcast receiver should have solved the whole problem. Why it is made so confusing?

Comment: "why it is so inefficient or battery consuming to update notification every minute?" -- the key to battery life is to have the CPU and radios powered down the vast majority of the time. The OS itself has gone to great lengths to ensure that periodic work can be performed in a controlled fashion and very infrequently. Device manufacturers [have done even more](https://dontkillmyapp.com/), because battery life is a key determinant of user satisfaction with devices.

Comment: "Simply a TIME_TICK Broadcast receiver should have solved the whole problem" -- [most implicit broadcasts were banned six years ago](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/broadcasts/broadcast-exceptions?hl=en). In this case, the issue is also process churn: it takes a fair amount of work to get an app running. "Why it is made so confusing?" -- Google initially set up Android to be very open, then realized that side effects of that openness led to users being unhappy, such as due to short battery lives.

Comment: Please suggest nearest possible solution or any alternative to the above problem. Thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare: I now only need to update the notification  on date changed even when the app is closed and in power saving mode.  Please suggest appropriate technologies Alarm Manager, Service, Broadcast Receiver, Job Scheduler etc

Comment: @CommonsWare: Anticipating life saving answer from Mark Murphy aka Android God.

Comment: I would not have the `Notification` in the first place. You're welcome to experiment with `AlarmManager` and the "exact and allow while idle" methods on it.